# How to create a AWS LB Listener from CloudFormation that returns a fixed response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

From the Load Balancer Lister configuration page, in the AWS Console it allows you to create a listener with a Default Action as shown here:

[image: Valid Default Actions]

The Fixed Response option allows you to specify an http return code and a body:

[image: Return Fixed Response]

Below is sample known-valid CloudFormation. Not sure how to edit this to support non-forwarding operations.

```
MyServicesLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
        LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyServicesLoadBalancer
        Port: 80
        Protocol: HTTP
        DefaultActions:
            - Type: forward
              TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyServicesTargetGroup
```

How do I do this with CloudFormation? The [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-defaultactions.html) seems to suggest only the Forward rule is supported in CloudFormation.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<s>Not possible yet. It has been requested on the [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=861188) but no ETA.</s>

According to the [Release History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) of AWS CloudFormation, the feature was added on Nov 19, 2018. This should replicate the fixed response you shown with the console pictures.

```yaml
MyServicesLoadBalancerListener:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyServicesLoadBalancer
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: fixed-response
        FixedResponseConfig:
          ContentType: "text/plain"
          MessageBody: "You've reached the listener! Congrats!"
          StatusCode: "503"
```

Comment: Great find. Thank you.

Comment: I see the aws elbv2 CLI is able to create the listener with the redirect option: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-listener.html so that's probably the best alternative for those looking to automate this.

Comment: @Jared if you wanna go the long route, you can create an AWS Lambda function to add the proper listener and use a Custom-resource to create in your CloudFormation template. I started doing it but stopped half-way through. If I manage to finish it, I will update this answer with my code.

Comment: @Jared cloudformation now supports creating this. I've updated my answer with the new code.

Comment: Nice @tyron! I'm impressed!